# how to convert the format of datetime picker and store date in mysql data base

Tags: vb.net

```
    sqlcon = New MySqlConnection
    sqlcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=soumya;database=bams;"
    Dim da, da1 As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds, ds1 As New DataSet
    Dim attendedclass, noofclass As Integer
    Dim query, query1 As String
    Dim yr, mon, day, yr1, mon1, day1 As Integer
    yr = DateTimePicker1.Value.Year
    yr1 = DateTimePicker2.Value.Year
    day = DateTimePicker1.Value.Day
    day1 = DateTimePicker2.Value.Day
    mon = DateTimePicker1.Value.Month
    mon1 = DateTimePicker2.Value.Month

    sqlcon.Open()
    query1 = "select * from attendence_master where ( REGISTER_NO='" & TextBox1.Text & "' ) and ( SUBJECT='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() & "' ) and ( LECTURER_NAME='" & TextBox4.Text & "' ) and ( CLASS ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() & "' ) and ( DAY  between " & day & " and " & day1 & ")  and ( MONTH between " & mon & " and " & mon1 & " ) and (YEAR between " & yr & " and " & yr1 & ")"
    sqlcom = New MySqlCommand(query1, sqlcon)
    da1 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlcom)
    da1.Fill(ds1)
    noofclass = ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count()
    query = "select * from attendence_master where ( REGISTER_NO='" & TextBox1.Text & "')  and ( SUBJECT='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.text & "' )  and ( LECTURER_NAME='" & TextBox4.Text & "' ) and ( ATTENDENCE='P' ) and ( CLASS ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() & "' ) and  ( DAY  between " & day & " and " & day1 & ")  and ( MONTH between " & mon & " and " & mon1 & " ) and (YEAR between " & yr & " and " & yr1 & ")"
    sqlcom = New MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon)
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlcom)
    da.Fill(ds)
    attendedclass = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    sqlcon.Close()
```

i cannot store date in mysql data base , cz i cld nt convert the format of datetimepicker n vb , . now i hve split the values of dtpicker and stored it as integer n data base ,.. need help to execute the query .. help plz .. ty

Comment: What error you getting now?? while saving date in database

Comment: query = "select * from attendence_master where ( REGISTER_NO='" & TextBox1.Text & "')  and ( SUBJECT='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.text & "' )  and ( LECTURER_NAME='" & TextBox4.Text & "' ) and ( ATTENDENCE='P' ) and ( CLASS ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() & "' ) and  ( DAY  between " & day & " and " & day1 & ")  and ( MONTH between " & mon & " and " & mon1 & " ) and (YEAR between " & yr & " and " & yr1 & ")"
    sqlcom = New MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon)
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlcom)
    da.Fill(ds) i have error in ths section

Comment: Public member 'text' on type 'String' not found.

Comment: what is the data type of DAY,YEAR and MONTH in table

Comment: int ! database is mysql

Comment: {"Public member 'text' on type 'String' not found."}

Comment: On a separate note you should use SQL parameters. You are open to **SQL injection**. It would also help to reduce syntax issues.

Comment: What does "_cz i cld nt_" mean?

Answer (score 0):

replace this query and check. In your query you used fields day,month and year are keywords, so add brackets with that table fields in the where clause and check

```
  sqlcon = New MySqlConnection
sqlcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=soumya;database=bams;"
Dim da, da1 As MySqlDataAdapter
Dim ds, ds1 As New DataSet
Dim attendedclass, noofclass As Integer
Dim query, query1 As String
Dim yr, mon, day, yr1, mon1, day1 As Integer
yr = DateTimePicker1.Value.Year
yr1 = DateTimePicker2.Value.Year
day = DateTimePicker1.Value.Day
day1 = DateTimePicker2.Value.Day
mon = DateTimePicker1.Value.Month
mon1 = DateTimePicker2.Value.Month

sqlcon.Open()
query1 = "select * from attendence_master where ( REGISTER_NO='" & TextBox1.Text & "' ) and ( SUBJECT='" & ComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString() & "' ) and ( LECTURER_NAME='" & TextBox4.Text & "' ) and ( CLASS ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() & "' ) and ( `DAY`  between " & day & " and " & day1 & ")  and ( `MONTH` between " & mon & " and " & mon1 & " ) and (`YEAR` between " & yr & " and " & yr1 & ")"
sqlcom = New MySqlCommand(query1, sqlcon)
da1 = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlcom)
da1.Fill(ds1)
noofclass = ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count()
query = "select * from attendence_master where ( REGISTER_NO='" & TextBox1.Text & "')  and ( SUBJECT='" & ComboBox1.SelectedText.text & "' )  and ( LECTURER_NAME='" & TextBox4.Text & "' ) and ( ATTENDENCE='P' ) and ( CLASS ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() & "' ) and  ( `DAY`  between " & day & " and " & day1 & ")  and ( `MONTH` between " & mon & " and " & mon1 & " ) and (`YEAR` between " & yr & " and " & yr1 & ")"
sqlcom = New MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon)
da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlcom)
da.Fill(ds)
attendedclass = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count()
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
sqlcon.Close()
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[DAY]  between 26 and 28)  and ( [MONTH] between 3 and 3 ) and ([YEAR] between 2' at line 1----

Comment: i found out the error ! SUBJECT='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.text & "' i changed it to ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() and it dsnt show any error ! but its not getting any results from db

Comment: there is no error reported whn i execute query ! but the dataset has no values in it ! i m not getting any results from data base

Comment: CLASS SUBJECT LECTURER_NAME TIME[FROM] TIME[TO] YEAR MONTH DAY STUDENT_NAME REGISTER_NO ATTENDENCE
 I BCA  A C++ arun123 9 10 2017 3 27 Sanvi 148040601 P
 I BCA  A C++ arun123 9 10 2017 3 27 Vismaya 148040602 A
 I BCA  A C++ arun123 9 10 2017 3 27 Medha 148040603 P
 I BCA  A C++ arun123 9 10 2017 3 27 Vinayaka 148040604 P
 I BCA  A C++ arun123 11 12 2017 3 28 Sanvi 148040601 P
 I BCA  A C++ arun123 11 12 2017 3 28 Vismaya 148040602 P
 I BCA  A C++ arun123 11 12 2017 3 28 Medha 148040603 P
 I BCA  A C++ arun123 11 12 2017 3 28 Vinayaka 148040604 P

Comment: @soumyak i have edited my answer. change the combox values from ComboBox1.Selecteditem.ToString() to ComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString().

Comment: not working !! is there any way to chnge the format of dayetimepicker in vb to yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: will between clause work if there are multiple between ?

Comment: @soumyak definitely between clause work with multiple fields. now i have update my answer. change the brackets from [] to {} for where clause fields. check and tell

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '}  between 26 and 28)  and ( {MONTH} between 3 and 3 ) and  ( {YEAR} between 201' at line 1

Comment: @soumyak change your where clause fields like {DAY} to `DAY` see the answer

Comment: how to add parameters to to my above query

Comment: please go through this link and see the answer for adding parameters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: ty ! and how to get database values to datagrid view

Comment: @soumyak you using windows application or web application

Comment: @soumyak use this code to bind database values to data grid view DataGridView1.DataSource = ds DataGridView1.databind()

Comment: cannot use bind function ! its windows app ! not web

Comment: @soumyak okay fine. leave the bind function :)

Comment: the query select * from attendence_master ,it works and retrieves data to datagrid but if i use two or more  conditions then it doesnt retrieve any value

Comment: @soumyak because there is no records matches in database for the input given by you. check the database manually for the given input.

Comment: Yeah.. now it works fine..as u said there was no record matching the value in the db

Comment: Ahaan fine.. but too late:) @soumyak